# Why was this question about USB ports closed as a duplicate of a newer question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicate

The question [Correctly inserting a USB connector on the first try](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/5995/correctly-inserting-a-usb-connector-on-the-first-try), was asked about a week ago, and it is a duplicate of the earlier question [How can I make sure I get the USB plug in the right way up?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1627/how-can-i-make-sure-i-get-the-usb-plug-in-the-right-way-up). However, the *older* question has closed as a duplicate of the newer one, which isn't really what duplicates are meant for. It's even in the duplicate close text:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question.

I can understand changing the convention in cases where one question is of extremely poor quality, but that just isn't the case here. Why was this  older question closed as a duplicate of the newer one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Done.

I reopened the older question and closed the newer as a duplicate of the older. I then merged the older question into the newer.

My reasoning behind this is **not** that the old question has automatic priority, but that it is the better question.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is not always the case when the newer questions are closed as dupes of older ones; often the question with *better* answers is a dupe target, as it appears to be in this case: I believe that the newer one has more complete and interesting answers and therefore should be a target for closing similar questions. I am afraid I can't agree with [@Mooseman](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2474) (*edit*: now just [rev 1](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/2474/1) :)).

Also, just a side note for mods: I'd merge these questions.

Comment: If both questions have good answers, which in this case they do, then merging would be a good solution. In fact, it's exactly what should be done. However, closing an older question as a dup of a newer one based solely on the answers just isn't what dup votes are meant for.

Comment: @Wip "closing an older question as a dup of a newer one based solely on the answers just isn't what dup votes are meant for" - that's one function of dupe votes, if you don't know.

Comment: Not really, no . When both questions have good answers, then the questions should be merged. That's why merging exists. Duplicate votes are intended to keep all the answers in one place. If a question gets good answers before it's dup closed, then it should be merged.

Comment: In anycase, this situation has been resolved in a fantastic way, so no point continuing to discuss when to dup and when not to dup.